# How can I make a Magento site wide search?

Tags: php, search, magento

Okay. This is propably very basic and noobie, but I have about 20+ stores inside one Magento site. I want to make the default search not only search the current store, but all other stores that are in the systems aswell.

Kinda like the global search in backend.

The frontend search should search those 20+ sites which are under the same site.

I have tried many things, but it doesn't seem to work.

Please help me — if someone knows something, because I really need to make this search work.

- Big site

  - Store
  - Store 2
  - Store 10
  - Store 20

I need to do a search in *Big Site* and display all the results.

**Big thanks!**

Comment: What have you tried? You *could* just search the relevant tables that is associated with each individual site. Or, you could implement a local Google Search.

Comment: I haven't built nothing by myself. I've tried to use magento's own search engine to "extend" but without luck. The best solution would be to "extend" Magento, because that would break the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that You are talking CatalogSearch core module.

Try to remove `->addStoreFilter()` from `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection()` method. Should work.

**EDIT**

And before removing this method check if store == Big Store